# what do I need to run python on my webserver?

Tags: apache-2.2, python

what do I need to run python on my webserver ?

Should I enable some Apache module ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you also look at [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). It's a nice alternative to running mod_python.  Also, depending on your application, FastCGI is also an option (see packages like [flup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup/1.0.3.dev-20100221), which kind of acts as a bridge between FastCGI & WSGI).

Comment: +1 mod_wsgi is the preferred way of doing it these days.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you need [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/).

Or you can enable cgi support by putting in a `AddHandler cgi-script .py` directive in your httpd.conf...You'll need to put a cgi shebang on the first line of your script as well (i.e. `!#/usr/bin/python`).